# How do we convert MultiColumnText to ColumnText in iText?

Tags: java, itext, openpdf

This is the code I have using OpenPDF (old version of iText 4). I searched for possible solutions online but all the implementations of ColumnText were confusing. I tried to implement it also but didn't get the the expected results.

```
MultiColumnText mct = new MultiColumnText();
mct.addReguarColumns(document.left(), document.right(), column.gutter, column.colNum);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Testing");
mct.addElement(p);
document.add(mct);
```

This was with MultiColumnText. Now, I was testing iText 5 and found out MultiColumnText is removed. I saw one question here that was for C# and I changed the code to following to support ColumnText:

```
ColumnText mct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
float middle = (document.left() + document.right()) / 2;
float[][] COLUMNS = {
                { document.left(), document.bottom(), middle - 15, document.top() } ,
                { middle + 15, document.bottom(), document.right(), document.top() }
        };
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Testing");
mct.addElement(p);
int col = 0;
int count = 0;
int status = ColumnText.START_COLUMN;
while (ColumnText.hasMoreText(status)) {
mct.setSimpleColumn(
COLUMNS[col][0], COLUMNS[col][1],
COLUMNS[col][2], COLUMNS[col][3]);
status = mct.go();
if (++count > 1) {
      count = 0;
      document.newPage();
}
}
```

But the output was a mess. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Note that iText 4 has never existed. It was (wrongfully) released by a third party not associated with iText in any way who (wrongfully) used project ID's belonging to iText. If upgrading to iText 7 is an option: upgrade to iText 7, and use the `ColumnDocumentRenderer` as described in the [tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2). You'll have to upgrade anyway if you want to use iText in a commercial context, because [versions older than iText 5 have legal issues](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5).

Comment: Apart from the legal issues with iText 4, there are obviously also the technical issues that you experienced. The people releasing iText 4 based their release on a version of iText that dates from July 2009. I hope you understand that many technical problems were solved in the later versions that were released in the last 9 years. I voted to close this question because you can't expect support on an unofficial version that dates from 2009 when you can solve your problem by upgrading to a version from 2018.

Comment: What about iText 5? If I have to switch to iText 7 then I'll have to change a whole lot. Also, by iText 4 above, I meant OpenPDF (which says is a fork of iText 4). Can we fix the above code using iText 5? Also, I am in a testing phase right now and so if I like the library, I will buy it. I know you are the author but I need to see what I am getting into.

Comment: Hahaha, OpenPDF is a joke. That's a release by a single developer who doesn't know enough about PDF nor about iText to fix problems like the one you experienced. iText 5 is no longer supported for free (only paying customers get support), but the fact that the `setSimpleColumn()` method accepts a `Rectangle` object as parameter makes things easier. Your paragraph is too small to test your code. I'll provide an answer based on the official documentation (it's weird that you refer to a C# example instead of consulting the official FAQ).

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the official documentation, more specifically the FAQ question [How to fit a String inside a rectangle?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-fit-string-inside-rectangle) in the section [Absolute positioning of text](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/absolute-positioning-text).

In the answer to that question, it says:

> If you can distribute the content over different pages, you don't need
>   simulation mode, you just need to insert a document.newPage();
>
> ```
> ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
> ct.setSimpleColumn(rect);
> int status = ct.go();
> while (ColumnText.hasMoreText(status)) {
>     document.newPage();
>     ct.setSimpleColumn(rect);
>     status = ct.go();
> }
> ```
>
> In this example `rect` contains the coordinates of the rectangle.

Granted, in this example, there's only one rectangle for each page, but you can easily adapt the code like this:

If you can distribute the content over different pages, you don't need simulation mode, you just need to insert a document.newPage();

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
ct.setSimpleColumn(rect[0]);
ct.go();
ct.setSimpleColumn(rect[1]);
int status = ct.go();
while (ColumnText.hasMoreText(status)) {
    document.newPage();
    ct.setSimpleColumn(rect[0]);
    ct.go();
    ct.setSimpleColumn(rect[1]);
    status = ct.go();
```

}

In this example `rect[]` is an array of two `Rectangle` objects, one for the left column, one for the right column.

Comment: I am just curious but how easy will it be to switch from iText 5 to iText 7?

Comment: The syntax is very different, but dealing with objects is more intuitive. It's impossible to tell you how easy or how difficult it would be, because that all depends on the size of your project, and which functionality you are using.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I decided to upgrade to iText7 and it did fix my columns. But, I am now having a small issue. Can you please help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084709/switch-between-columndocumentrenderer-and-documentrenderer-in-same-page