# Itext 7 mixed full body and column layout on the same page

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I'm using iText 7 and am attempting to create a document with mixed layout on the same page.

I have a need to have full body layout followed by column layout on the same page, with the columns possibly flowing onto subsequent pages. Then I need to revert back to full body layout, again followed by columns starting on the same page as the full body section, and the columns again possibly flowing onto subsequent pages.

However, this only seems to work where the columns start on page 1 of the generated document. If not, the text for the columns seems to want to be placed on previous pages with incorrect layout. I have tried the example here:

[Switch between ColumnDocumentRenderer and DocumentRenderer in same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084709/switch-between-columndocumentrenderer-and-documentrenderer-in-same-page)

Unfortunately, it does not work in my scenario. Here is the result of a lorem ipsum test:

[image: Lorem Ipsum test]

Can anyone please help?

**UPDATE:**
I'm getting closer to a solution. I've updated my code and the text in columns and bull body layout does not now overlap. However, when starting column rendering on the same page after a paragraph that overflows onto a subsequent page in full body layout, the starting portion of the text in that section of column layout goes missing. Also rendering appears to begin on a new page, not the same page as the previously rendered paragraph that overlfowed onto a subsequent page in full body layout.

I am using the following code (3 classes):

```
package org.jsb.DocGen;

import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.DrawContext;
import com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.IRenderer;
import com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.ParagraphRenderer;

import lombok.Getter;

public final class CustomParagraphRenderer extends ParagraphRenderer {
    private @Getter float y = 0.0f;

    public CustomParagraphRenderer(Paragraph modelElement) {
        super(modelElement);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawBorder(DrawContext drawContext) {
        super.drawBorder(drawContext);
        this.y = getOccupiedAreaBBox().getBottom();
    }

    @Override
    public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
        return new CustomParagraphRenderer((Paragraph) modelElement);
    }

}


package org.jsb.DocGen;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.layout.ColumnDocumentRenderer;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;

public class CustomColumnDocumentRenderer extends ColumnDocumentRenderer {

    private Rectangle [] columns2 = null;

    public CustomColumnDocumentRenderer(Document document, Rectangle [] columns1, Rectangle [] columns2) {
        super(document, columns1);
        this.columns2 = columns2;
    }

    @Override
    protected PageSize addNewPage(PageSize customPageSize) {
        PageSize size = super.addNewPage(customPageSize);
        super.columns = this.columns2;
        return size;
    }

}



package org.jsb.DocGen;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.AreaBreak;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.AreaBreakType;
import com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.DocumentRenderer;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public final class ColumnTest {

    @Test
    public final void test() {
        Document document = null;
        String dest = String.format("%s/Desktop/mixedrenderers.pdf", System.getProperty("user.home")).replace("\\", "/").replace("//", "/");
        File file = new File(dest);
        if(file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        try(
                PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(dest);
                PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        ) {
            String [] loremipsums = {
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam interdum sollicitudin velit nec semper. Aliquam porta venenatis tortor, et viverra nisl accumsan non. Sed euismod tincidunt ex et porttitor. Duis lacinia efficitur auctor. Quisque eros quam, maximus et suscipit quis, tempor fringilla lorem. Donec hendrerit hendrerit vehicula. Integer vulputate fermentum arcu in tincidunt. Fusce euismod sapien id iaculis efficitur. Suspendisse potenti.",
                "Proin condimentum lorem a enim cursus tincidunt. Proin dui ex, faucibus semper tincidunt vitae, lobortis ut urna. Nullam iaculis neque accumsan urna consectetur accumsan. Mauris quis est nunc. Pellentesque vitae urna congue, dignissim lacus quis, volutpat ipsum. Duis arcu neque, convallis et nunc aliquet, sollicitudin finibus sem. Donec malesuada commodo purus. Quisque imperdiet elementum suscipit. Cras fringilla dolor a nunc placerat porta. In id consequat justo, eget dictum mauris. Sed felis est, tristique vulputate nunc non, bibendum consequat nibh. Ut imperdiet sit amet lectus sed bibendum. Sed vitae blandit nibh, at tincidunt nisi. Nunc vulputate mi in ipsum egestas posuere eget ac arcu. Duis at sagittis sapien.",
                "Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean odio lorem, porttitor id ante id, dapibus blandit orci. Donec molestie luctus neque sit amet fermentum. Aliquam nec tempus nulla. Aenean nec auctor metus. Curabitur non ultrices enim. In nec orci efficitur, vestibulum sem ut, molestie metus. Aenean sit amet purus finibus, tempor nibh et, ultrices orci. Fusce elementum fringilla eros, vel facilisis justo placerat et. Proin sagittis, nunc vitae rutrum porttitor, libero risus vulputate ipsum, quis dignissim sapien orci non quam. Cras eu dolor volutpat, blandit lacus vitae, venenatis felis. Sed laoreet mi non turpis feugiat pharetra. Fusce sem est, condimentum at elit a, consequat condimentum mauris. Vestibulum est est, tincidunt sed varius ac, gravida eget purus. Pellentesque sit amet nibh sit amet mi tincidunt tempor non vitae quam.",
                "Sed a augue nunc. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent hendrerit sem lacus, sodales bibendum nunc pretium vel. Proin tincidunt, orci porttitor suscipit consectetur, neque dui fringilla neque, vitae dapibus orci libero quis leo. Nunc velit arcu, accumsan et felis ut, sodales varius libero. Quisque vitae iaculis ante. Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus fringilla sollicitudin mollis. Etiam nulla dolor, placerat at molestie a, lobortis et diam. Phasellus egestas aliquet pellentesque. Etiam pretium sapien sed nunc vehicula, in fermentum quam euismod. Proin auctor leo eu urna tempus, quis auctor felis bibendum. Quisque sollicitudin lacinia urna a ultricies. Ut volutpat eros tristique tempor imperdiet. Sed sit amet nulla non elit sollicitudin rutrum. In suscipit mollis purus, non efficitur justo molestie tempus.",
                "Quisque sed est odio. Ut et sodales nulla, ornare mollis nunc. Curabitur nec bibendum nunc. Phasellus lobortis auctor faucibus. Praesent quis metus at diam mollis laoreet. Nulla viverra risus in blandit interdum. Praesent sed tortor id felis tincidunt luctus nec vel dolor. Vivamus hendrerit, enim vel sollicitudin consequat, dui augue tincidunt metus, quis pellentesque dui ante non leo. Mauris ultricies elit id tempus vehicula. Nunc mauris arcu, accumsan quis lorem quis, pharetra tincidunt sem. Donec ut lacus molestie dolor convallis elementum tincidunt vitae sem. Fusce viverra tortor libero, vitae ultricies lectus hendrerit interdum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce ante eros, pretium at pellentesque id, auctor et mi. Nam ut accumsan dolor, ac cursus elit. Nunc nec sapien blandit, volutpat tortor eget, aliquet lacus.",
            };
            Paragraph para = null;
            CustomParagraphRenderer paragraphRenderer = null;

            document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4);
            document.setRenderer(new DocumentRenderer(document));

            // One full body paragraph that does not flow onto subsequent pages ...
            para = new Paragraph().add(loremipsums[0]);
            paragraphRenderer = new CustomParagraphRenderer(para);
            para.setNextRenderer(paragraphRenderer);
            document.add(para);

            // ... followed by column layout starting on the same page and flowing onto subsequent pages.
            float y = paragraphRenderer.getY();
            float offSet = 36; // margins
            float gutter = 23; // column gap
            float columnWidth = (PageSize.A4.getWidth() - offSet * 2) / 2 - gutter;
            float columnHeight1 = y - offSet * 2;
            Rectangle[] columns1 = {
                new Rectangle(offSet, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight1),
                new Rectangle(offSet + columnWidth + gutter, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight1)
            };
            float columnHeight2 = PageSize.A4.getHeight() - offSet * 2;
            Rectangle[] columns2 = {
                new Rectangle(offSet, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight2),
                new Rectangle(offSet + columnWidth + gutter, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight2)};
            document.setRenderer(new CustomColumnDocumentRenderer(document, columns1, columns2));  
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                for(String loremipsum : loremipsums) {
                    document.add(new Paragraph(loremipsum));
                }
            }

            // Then followed by full body paragraphs stating on the page after the column layout and flowing onto subsequent pages ...
            document.setRenderer(new DocumentRenderer(document));
            document.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
            document.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                for(String loremipsum : loremipsums) {
                    para = new Paragraph().add(loremipsum);
                    paragraphRenderer = new CustomParagraphRenderer(para);
                    para.setNextRenderer(paragraphRenderer);
                    document.add(para);
                }
            }

            // ... finally followed by column layout starting on the same page as the last paragraph as the previous full body layout, and flowing onto subsequent pages.
            // BUG: However - this starts rendering at the top of a new page. It does NOT begin rendering on the same page as the last full body paragraph previously rendered.
            // BUG: And some of the text in gets lost at the start of rendering this section.
            y = ((CustomParagraphRenderer)para.getRenderer()).getY();
            offSet = 36; // margins
            gutter = 23; // column gap
            columnWidth = (PageSize.A4.getWidth() - offSet * 2) / 2 - gutter;
            columnHeight1 = y - offSet * 2;
            columns1 = new Rectangle[2];
            columns1[0] = new Rectangle(offSet, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight1);
            columns1[1] = new Rectangle(offSet + columnWidth + gutter, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight1);
            columnHeight2 = PageSize.A4.getHeight() - offSet * 2;
            columns2 = new Rectangle[2];
            columns2[0] = new Rectangle(offSet, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight2);
            columns2[1] = new Rectangle(offSet + columnWidth + gutter, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight2);
            document.setRenderer(new CustomColumnDocumentRenderer(document, columns1, columns2));
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                for(String loremipsum : loremipsums) {
                    document.add(new Paragraph(loremipsum));
                }
            }

            document.flush();
            document.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            log.error(null, e);
        } finally {
            if(document != null) {
                document.close();
            }
        }
        if(file.exists()) {
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error(null, e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Ideas anyone? I would much appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: The switch between single column and multicolumn text is triggered by what? Does it happen at certain points of the source text? Or does it happen at fixed heights of given pages?

Comment: Hi there. I've updated the code in the sample that whoes how I'm switching renderers. It's only test code so it's not pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With two changes your updated code creates the desired output. Unfortunately I don't understand the necessity of the second of those changes, maybe an iText developer should explain either that it makes sense or propose a better one.

#### The `CustomParagraphRenderer`

One problem is due to the way you determine the **y** coordinate:

```
y = ((CustomParagraphRenderer)para.getRenderer()).getY();
```

Depending on the way the layout process went, the current renderer of the paragraph may not have been used at all, so its **y** value may still be 0 as initialized. This in turn  will make your `columns1` a rectangle with negative height which devours some text without rendering this text visibly.

You can get rid of this problem by making the **y** variable static.

```
private static float y = 0.0f;
```

(I don't use that `@Getter` annotation you use, so I don't know whether it can handle static variables, too. If not, simply create an explicit getter...)

Now any unused `CustomParagraphRenderer` instance cannot introduce `0` values anymore.

The result now: All text is there, i.e. no text is lost anymore. Unfortunately, though, the two-column rendering starts on the page before resulting in overlapping text again. To solve this:

#### An additional `NEXT_PAGE AreaBreak`

This overlapping text issue can be resolved by adding a `new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE)` after setting the new renderer, before adding content:

```
...
columns2 = new Rectangle[2];
columns2[0] = new Rectangle(offSet, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight2);
columns2[1] = new Rectangle(offSet + columnWidth + gutter, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight2);
document.setRenderer(new CustomColumnDocumentRenderer(document, columns1, columns2));
document.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE)); // <---
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for(String loremipsum : loremipsums) {
        document.add(new Paragraph(loremipsum));
    }
}
...
```

The result: Now the double-column text starts after the overflow paragraph part in single-column layout, just as desired.

But I do not understand why this is necessary. I see that you used the same technique to prevent overlapping text at previous renderer changes, but IMO it should not be necessary. Unfortunately I'm not deep enough into this to explain, let alone provide a more reasonable solution for this.

---

The complete test code can be found in this [MixedColumnLayout](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/content/MixedColumnLayout.java#L26) unit test class.

Comment: Thank you for this.